# Manual API rate limiting

Tags: r, github, rate-limiting

I am trying to write a manual rate-limiting function for the `rgithub` package. So far this is what I have:

```
library(rgithub)

pull <- function(i){
 commits <- get.pull.request.commits(owner = owner, repo = repo, id = i, ctx = get.github.context(), per_page=100)
 links <- digest_header_links(commits)
 number_of_pages <- links[2,]$page
 if (number_of_pages != 0)
   try_default(for (n in 1:number_of_pages){
    if (as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-remaining`) < 5)
     Sys.sleep(as.integer(commits$headers$`x-ratelimit-reset`)-as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) %>% as.integer())
  else
    get.pull.request.commits(owner = owner, repo = repo, id = i, ctx = get.github.context(), per_page=100, page = n)
}, default = NULL)
else 
   return(commits)
}

list <- c(500, 501, 502)

pull_lists <- lapply(list, pull)
```

The intention i that if the `x-ratelimit-remaining` variable goes below a certain threshold the script should wait until the time specified in `x-ratelimit-reset` has passed, and then continue the script. However, I'm not sure if this is the actual behavior of the `if else` set up that I have here.

The function runs fine, but I have some doubts about whether it actually does the rate limiting or whether it somehow skips that steps. Hence I ask: a) how can I find out if it actually does rate-limiting, and b) if not, how can I rewrite it so that it actually does rate limiting? Would a `while` condition/loop perhaps be better?

Comment: As is your line `}, default = NULL)` is not corresponding to anything above. Could you correct it? The following `else` also has no corresponding `if` above.

Comment: @cmbarbu: should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if it does the rate limiting changing `5` to a large enough number and adding a display of the timing of `Sys.sleep` using:

```
print(system.time(Sys.sleep(...)))
```

That said, the function seems ok to me, unfortunately I cannot test it easily as rgithub is not available for my version of R (3.1.3).

Answer (score 0):

Not a canonical answer, but some working example.
You should add some logging in your script, even kind of `write.csv(append=TRUE)`.

I've implemented automatic *antiddos* process which prevent your ip to be banned by the exchange market. You can find it [jangorecki/Rbitcoin/R/utils.R](https://github.com/jangorecki/Rbitcoin/blob/2f2eeedecc5d4b97c590c48d0ba7aab1b69f0970/R/utils.R#L103).
`Rbitcoin.last_api_call` is env object stored in package namespace, kind of session package cache.
This can help you with setting it in your package.

You should also consider a optional *parallel* supported version. Linking to database with concurrency read. My function can be easy modified to queue call and recheck timing every X seconds.

**Edit**
I forget to add that mentioned function support multiple *source systems*. That allows for example to extend your rgithub for bitbucket, etc. and still effectively manage API rate limiting.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to add logging to the script?

Comment: @histelheim check `futile.logger` on CRAN. It's a really awesome and useful package.

Comment: @histelheim futile.logger is for kind of more extended logging, if you want to just see if your process works you can use anything which will print the state. From printing to console `message(paste("time spent waiting:",x))` to printing to file `write.csv(..., append=TRUE)`, or many of different variations.  
I my linked example I used option `verbose` and function `cat` to print seconds spent waiting to console.